# How to get model of device in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, model

I want to get device model `(Settings->General->About->Model)` through code. I used:

```
 NSString*  model=[[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
```

Above code returns "iPhone".  But I need to get device model value that is shown in `(Settings->General->About->Model)`. For example in my iPhone it is "MD128HN/A. Please see the attached snapshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *platform = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;

NSLog(@"[UIDevice currentDevice].model: %@",platform);
NSLog(@"[UIDevice currentDevice].description: %@",[UIDevice currentDevice].description);
NSLog(@"[UIDevice currentDevice].localizedModel: %@",[UIDevice currentDevice].localizedModel);
NSLog(@"[UIDevice currentDevice].name: %@",[UIDevice currentDevice].name);
NSLog(@"[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion: %@",[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion);
NSLog(@"[UIDevice currentDevice].systemName: %@",[UIDevice currentDevice].systemName);
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not correct answer. I want to print the value I rounded in snapshot please check the snapshot.